# Mongodb query on reference document

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schema defined in mongoose as follows,

Model: Article

```
var articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    sequenceId: String
    title: String,
    abstract: String,
    authors: [String],
    date: Date,
    words: [{
        selectedWord: String,
        details: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Word' }
    }],
    otherTags: [String]
})
```

Model: Word

```
var wordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    preferredWord: String,
    synonyms: [String],
    category: String
})
```

Now I am trying to get 2 sets of results for the following scenarios,

1. Get all the articles that have 'wordAbc' and/or 'wordXyz' in either **selectedWord**, **preferredWord** or **synonyms**
2. Get all the unique words in **selectedWord**, **preferredWord** and **synonyms** across all the articles in the database

What would be the best/efficient way perform query using mongoose?

For the first result I tried that partial query but getting the CastError message,

```
Article.find({})
.populate( 'words', null, { 'details': {$in: ['wordAbc', 'wordXyz']}} )
.exec(function(err, docs) {});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve both the things you want using aggregation pipeline.

> 1. Get all the articles that have 'wordAbc' and/or 'wordXyz' in either
>      selectedWord, preferredWord or synonyms

First you will need to populate all the words in `details` field of `words` array, and then match the articles based on `selectedWord`, `preferredWord` or `synonyms`.

This can be achieved like this:

```
Article.aggregate([{
    $unwind : {
        path :"$words",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays :true
    }
},{
    $lookup : {
        from : "words",
        localField : "words.details",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as : "words.details"
    }
},{
    $unwind : {
        path : "$words.details",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true
    }
},{
    $match : {
        $or : [{
            "words.selectedWord" : {$in: ['wordAbc', 'wordXyz']}
        },{
            "words.details.preferredWord" : {$in: ['wordAbc', 'wordXyz']}
        },{
            "words.details.synonyms" : {$in: ['wordAbc', 'wordXyz']}
        }]
    }
},{
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        title : {$first : "$title"},
        abstract : {$first : "$abstract"},
        authors : {$first : "$authors"},
        date : {$first : "$date"},
        words: {$push : "$words"},
        otherTags: {$first : "$otherTags"}
    }
}])
```

> 2. Get all the unique words in selectedWord, preferredWord and synonyms
>      across all the articles in the database

In this case you will have to `unwind` `words` array and then `populate` `words.details`  from `words` collection, and then `unwind` `synonyms` array, so that we can create a set of `selectedWord`, `preferredWord` and `synonyms` across all the `articles`, and then finally make a whole set of all the unique words in the last stage of aggregation pipeline.

This can be achieved like this:

```
Article.aggregate([{
    $project : {
        words : "$words"
    }
},{
    $unwind : "$words" 
},{
    $lookup : {
        from : "words",
        localField : "words.details",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as : "words.details"
    }
},{
    $unwind : "$words.details"
},{
    $unwind : "$words.details.synonyms"
},{
    $project : {
        selectedWord : "$words.selectedWord",
        preferredWord : "$words.details.preferredWord",
        synonyms : "$words.details.synonyms"
    }
},{
    $group : {
        _id : "null",
        selectedWord : {$addToSet  :"$selectedWord"},
        preferredWord : {$addToSet  :"$preferredWord"},
        synonyms : {$addToSet  :"$synonyms"}
    }
},{
    $project : {
        commonWords : {$setUnion : ["$selectedWord","$preferredWord","$synonys"]}
    }
}])
```

Explanation of 2nd aggregation.

1. `$project` : We want only words, so i carried on words field of all the articles and removed all other unnecessary fields from the pipeline.
2. `$unwind` : we need to unwind the words array, so that we can $lookup words.details from words collection in the next stage of pipeline
3. `$lookup` : populate details from words collection.
4. `$unwind` : Since `$lookup` returns an array, we need to unwind it to make it an object
5. `$unwind` :  unwind `words.details.synonyms`, so that we can group them and create array of unique words in next stage of pipeline, At this stage, individual documents in aggregation pipeline will look something like this:

   ```
   {
       words : {
           selectedWord :"someword",
           details : {
               preferredWord : "otherword",
               synonym : "synonymword"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. `$project` : we needed this flatten the object structure. After this stage individual document in the pipeline would look like this:

   ```
   {
        selectedWord :"someword",
        preferredWord : "otherword",
        synonym : "synonymword"
   }
   ```
7. `$group` : combine all the `selectedWord` into one array, `preferredWord` into one array, and synonyms in one array, $addToSet is used to remove duplicate objects
8. `$project` : combine all the 3 arrays and create one array of unique Words

For details information on all the used operators of mongoDB, read respective documentations.

[$setUnion documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/)

[$addToSet documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/)

[$project documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

[$unwind documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

[Documentation of all the operators of mongodb aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

I hope this helps you out

Comment: Thanks Ravi for the step by step illustration. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One thing to add, The '$' sign need to be removed from the line $_id : "null", otherwise the code will through an MongoError: The field '$_id' must be an accumulator object

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry it was a mistake, I will edit it right away.

Comment: Your queries work fine when value exit in all the queried fields, selectedWord, details, preferredWord, and synonyms. But if any any of the field data is empty both queries 1 and 2 does not include the object. How can I make those fields optional in the query?

Comment: For example, a valid 'selectedWord' value doesn't show up when there is no ref in the 'details', 'preferredWord' or 'synonyms'. How can I overcome that?

Comment: You can use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true` with `$unwind` to keep the empty arrays as well. I will update the answer accordingly.